# C++: new call that behaves like calloc?

Tags: c++, new-operator, calloc

Is there a call I can make to `new` to have it zero out memory like `calloc`?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Contrary what some are saying in their answers, it *is* possible.

```
char * c = new char[N]();
```

Will zero initialize all the characters (in reality, it's called value-initialization. But value-initialization is going to be zero-initialization for all its members of an array of scalar type). If that's what you are after.

Worth to note that it does also work for (arrays of) class-types without user declared constructor in which case any member of them is value initialized:

```
struct T { int a; };
T *t = new T[1]();
assert(t[0].a == 0);
delete[] t;
```

It's not some extension or something. It worked and behaved the same way in C++98 too. Just there it was called default initialization instead of value initialization. Zero initialization, however, is done in both cases for scalars or arrays of scalar or POD types.

Comment: I learn something new each day from your posts! BTW, do you know why new[N](42) is not allowed?

Comment: T() is a special form: value-initialization or (what it was in c++98) default-initialization T(42), though, is direct initialization, and doesn't work for arrays

Comment: This is the specific scenario I was looking for, but all these other answers are great too!

Comment: Is this true even under the C++98 standard which does not have value initialization (or is it default initialization that C++98 doesn't have)? I've written about that differences between C++98 and C++03 value/default initialization, but I honestly can't remember the details without looking it up (which I'm either too lazy or unable to do at the moment).

Comment: Michael, yes i remember your post since it taught me value-initializations which i hadn't known before :) The same is true for c++98. But in case of a non-POD without user declared ctor, c++98 won't do any zero/value initializations of members, but instead delegate to the default constructor and leave members uninitialized.

Comment: Warning: this does NOT work for VC6. I've tried to compile on VC6 Debug builds, and it does NOT initialize the variables - treated just like c = new char[N].

Comment: Many other things won't work on VC6 either. If you need a C++ compiler, better use a new version of it (recent releases of VC++ are gratis (express editions))

Comment: I'm ok if some syntax does not work (i.e., compile failure) for VC6; but if something will get different results (and hard to be noticed), I'll prevent using it. Still many people & projects in this world is using VC6.

Comment: After looking at my notes, I'm reminded that the parens should make the new operator perform zero-initialization on POD types. If VC6 isn't doing this, then as litb mentions that looks to be non-conformant behavior (even for C++98).  However, in VC6's defense, this whole area of initialization behavior of the new operator is incredibly convoluted and confusing in the details.

Comment: Not to mention that VC6 actually slightly predates the C++98 standard :-)

Answer (score 11):

No but it's fairly easy to create a new version that acts like calloc.  It can be done in much the same way that the no-throw version of new is implemented.

SomeFile.h

```
struct zeromemory_t{};
extern const zeromemory_t zeromemory;
void* __cdcel operator new(size_t cbSize, const zeromemory_t&);
```

SomeFile.cpp

```
const zeromemory_t zeromemory;

void* _cdecl operator new(size_t cbSize, const zeromemory_t&)
{
    void *mem = ::operator new(cbSize);
    memset(mem,0,cbSize);
    return mem;
}
```

Now you can do the following to get new with zero'd memory

```
MyType* pMyType = new (zeromemory) MyType();
```

Additionally you'd need to do other fun things like define new[] which is fairly straight forward as well.

Comment: Just to point out the official name for this is placement new.  If danvin wants more info on the subject.  Can also be used for creating object caches ( think linux kernel slab cache )

Comment: s/opeartor/operator/ ;)  Might want to put as a warning, make sure to instantiate `const zeromemory_t zeromemory;` in exactly one compilation unit.

Comment: @ephemient, Fixed the misspell. Curious, how could the value as defined only in a .cpp file be included in more than one compilation unit?

Comment: What I meant is: if you #include "SomeFile.h" in multiple .cpp files, you should only write "const zeromemory_t zeromemory;" in one .cpp file -- no more, no less -- if they're going to be linked together.

Comment: @ephemient, gotcha. I meant for SomeFile.h and SomeFile.cpp to be a pair that was only done once.  Probably should have called it AllocUtil.h and AllocUtil.cpp or the like to make it clearer

Answer (score 4):

No. Also don't even think of doing something like:

```
YourClass *var = new YourClass;
memset(var, 0, sizeof(YourClass));
```

You could end up trashing your VTABLE (if your class has one).

I would recommend using constructors to clear the internal memory (variables) of your class.

Comment: I dunno; if he really wants to shoot himself in the foot that badly, is it ethical to stop him?  :-)

Comment: Definitely allocate and set your memory inside your class. Don't rely on memset. It works in many cases, but it's "undefined" in the spec.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. It will always default-initialize the allocated item(s), which in the case of primitives does nothing. You'll have to follow it up with a std::uninitialized_fill_n call or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a global overload of operator `new` and have it grab the raw memory from `calloc()`.  This way the memory gets wiped before constructors get to run so there's no problems there.

Any class that overrides new on its own will not get your special `calloc()`-based `new`, but then that class should be initializing itself correctly anyway.

Don't forget to override both `new` and `delete` and the array versions...

Something like:

```
#include <exception> // for std::bad_alloc
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h> // for calloc() and free()

void* operator new (size_t size)
{
 void *p=calloc(size, 1); 
 if (p==0) // did allocation succeed?
  throw std::bad_alloc(); 
 return p;
}


void operator delete (void *p)
{
 free(p); 
}

void* operator new[] (size_t size)
{
 void *p=calloc(size, 1); 
 if (p==0) // did allocation succeed?
  throw std::bad_alloc();
 return p;
}

void operator delete[] (void *p)
{
 free(p); 
}
```

Note that these simple versions aren't quite exactly what they should be - the `new` operator should run in a loop calling the `new_handler` (if one is installed) and only throwing the `bad_alloc` exception if there is no `new_handler`. Or something like that, I'll have to look it up and update later.

Oh, and you might want to also override the `no_throw` version as well.

Comment: What happens with classes that have virtual methods defined in this case?

Comment: Nothing unusual happens - the constructor runs normally.  It's just that the raw memory the constructor works on always happens to have been cleared.

Answer (score 1):

i use a macro:

```
#define newclear(TYPE) new(calloc(sizeof(TYPE), 1)) TYPE();
```

to use it:

```
Whatever* myWhatever = newclear(Whatever);
```

(this uses "placement new" like some other solutions here)

Comment: don't forget the # before define :D (apparently this site removes it.

Comment: there's actually a special formatting for source code.  Anything you indent by four spaces will get the special highlighting (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

No.You have to manually zero the memory out. Remember, `new` is not just about allocating memory, but also about initializing via constructors. This is where `calloc` is handy in C (which does not have initializer functions). You are free to write a wrapper over `new` or even use `calloc`, but most of the time for non-POD objects this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't insist using `new`, you can simply use vector: `vector<char> buffer; buffer.resize(newsize);` and the content will be zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
int* p_scalar = new int(5);//Does not create 5 elements, but initializes to 5
```

For arrays you can use something like memset.  For windows use ZeroMemory or SecureZeroMemory.

**Edit:** Please see @litb's post, he shows how you can initialize to 0 for arrays using non direct initialization like above.

Comment: try with array - it won't work (at least for ISO C++ - maybe some compilers with extension may allow it).

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    void* operator new(size_t bytes) {
        return calloc(bytes, 1);
    }
}
```

And you can override the global new operator if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
vector <char> v( 100, 0 );
```

which creates a contiguous array of 100 characters using new, and initialises them all to zero. You can then access the array with vector's [] operator, or by doing:

```
char * p = &v[0];
p[3] = 42;
```

Note this also frees you from having to call delete to free the allocated memory.